# Как при нажатии на кнопку заменить в ней не только текст, но и функционал Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Со сменой текста более менее понятно код выглядит примерно так даже если с ошибками:

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, height=600)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)  
frame = Frame(root)
btn1 = Button(frame, text='Автоматом', command = some)
btn1.pack(side='right')
frame.pack(side='bottom')

#Этот стоп должен срабатывать только после нажатия на кнопку  
def stop(event):
    return false    
def some():
        a = true
        btn1["text"] = "Стоп"
        while(a):
                step()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                a = stop()
```

Но как задать новый функционал я не понял.

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает сделать

```
btn1 = Button(frame, text='Новый текс', command = НовыйМетод)
```

снова. (Если так не работает, то можно вроде как удалить элемент `pack_forget` и заново его пересоздать)

Comment: Те Вы предлагаете создавать новую кнопку, или перезаписывать старую? В любом случае мне нужно было бы сделать тем методом, что я описал те => btn1["text"] = "текст" и btn1["Что-то"] = новый_функционал. Если это возможно конечно. Пока так